# Do any personality factors reduce illusory superiority?

Tags: personality, abnormal-psychology, bias, big-five

Apparently individuals suffering from schizotypy [lack illusory superiority](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4372844/) in one particular domain: evaluation of their affect. That is to say, neurotypicals overrate their positive affect (and underrate their negative one), whereas individuals with schizotypy don't do either relative to how their affect is perceived by others.

[image]

There's another article which concludes that the five-factor model is [good enough](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.psychres.2009.07.018) to capture schizotypy, although in practice (insofar) specialized tests are used to detect the latter.

[image]

That begs the following question: **do any of the big five personality factors**, especially those that load most heavily on schizotypy (neuroticism, introversion, low openness to experience) **have a moderating effect on illusory superiority (in some domain) on their own**? By "on their own" I mean: is there a correlation between any of the big five (or even HEXACO) factors and lessened illusory superiority (on some issue), including via an [interaction effect](http://methods.sagepub.com/reference/encyclopedia-of-survey-research-methods/n226.xml) of the factors, but found without segregating the sample into schizotypy and non-schizotypy?

N.B.: I'm aware of the controversy surrounding [depressive realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depressive_realism), but let's stick just to personality here.

Comment: Very interesting. Following it. interestingly i noticed many of the typically developed people do not want to know or let others tell real but problematic issues, instead they try manipulate own or others' mind to convince as if there is no problem, and as if there is no need to take action, and tries to fit in. Also this trait of people also claims as if a problem is accepted or validated the problem increases and as if they believe the problem does not exist, the problem disappears. The much absurd it may sound, they claims it.

Comment: I think typically developing human being have in general a tendency to have some degree of narcissistic personality trait, also some herd behaviour that drives them to control others and to want to be controlled by a leader or magical being.

Comment: This reminds me of [depressive realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depressive_realism) and likely faces the same challenges: Improved accuracy in some domains at the expense of reduced accuracy in others.